# Why is there an extra result handed back to me during this Python regex example?

Tags: python, regex

**Code:**

```
re.findall('(/\d\d\d\d)?','/2000')
```

**Result:**

> ['/2000', '']

**Code:**

```
re.findall('/\d\d\d\d?','/2000')
```

**Result:**

> ['/2000']

Why is the extra '' returned in the first example?
i am using the first example for django url configuration , is there a way i can prevent matching of '' ?

Comment: What URLs do you want to match, exactly? Please note that that would be *another* question ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because using the brackets you define a group, and then with `?` you ask for 0 to 1 repetitions of the group. Thus the empty string and `/2000` both match.

Answer (score 1):

the operator `?` will match 0 or 1 repetitions of the preceding expression, in the first case the preceding expression is `(/\d\d\d\d)`, while in the second is the last `\d`.

Therefore the first case the empty string `""` will be matched, as it contain zero repetition of the expression `(/\d\d\d\d)`

Comment: but ain't no  empty sting in '/2000' :P

Comment: There are an infinite number of empty strings in `/2000`. There's one between every character, and one between each of those, and so on *ad infinitum*. There are several at the beginning and end of the string too!

Comment: @bunny:  yes there is - there is always an empty string inside every string, just as the empty set is a subset of every other set.  Try `"" in "foo"` at the interactive prompt.

Comment: As Dave said there is an empty string in every string , quite philosophical :), anyway try `re.findall('(/\d\d\d\d)?','/20009')` notice the added 9 at the end of the matched string, it will give you two emtpy strings as a match, as it will match `''` once before the `9` and once at the end of the string, i think the last one matches at the end of the string due to the `/0` which reprensents the end of array of char* in C, hope it's clear now :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is what is happening: The regex engine starts off with its pointer before the first char in the target string. It greedily consumes the whole string and places the match result in the first list element. This leaves the internal pointer at the end of the string. But since the regex pattern can match nothingness, it successfully matches at the position at the end of the string too, Thus, there are two elements in the list.